# div element not displaying

Tags: html, css

I am currently designing a website that requires a div element to appear overlayed on top of an image when that image is hovered over. The images are in a carousel that expands and changes the size of them when they are hovered, and I would like the description (sc-desc) to appear with the same dimensions as the image on top of it when it is selected. currently, when I hover over the image, the description is nowhere to be found.

```css
section,
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

html ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.maincontent {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.layout-T1 {
  /*background-color: #333;*/
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 1fr;
  height: 1fr;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 88vh 33% 33% 33% 33% 33%;
  column-gap: 0px;
  row-gap: 0px;
}

.sc-T1 {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  overflow: hidden;
  aspect-ratio: 1.5/1;
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: 2.2%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-height: 88vh;
  padding: none none none none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.1px;
  border-color: #333;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
}

#sc-T1-a:hover {
  width: 84%;
  #sc-a-desc {
    display: shown !important;
  }
  #sc-T1-b {
    width: 1fr;
  }
  #sc-T1-c {
    width: 1fr;
  }
  #sc-c-desc {
    display: hidden !important;
  }
}

#sc-T1-b:hover {
  width: 84% !important;
  #sc-b-desc {
    display: shown !important;
  }
  #sc-T1-c {
    width: 1fr !important;
  }
  #sc-c-desc {
    display: hidden !important;
  }
  #sc-T1-a {
    width: 1fr !important;
  }
}

.sc-T1-I img {
  margin: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
  aspect-ratio: 1.26 / 1;
  height: 100%;
}

#sc-T1-a,
#sc-T1-b {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 7%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: width 0.25s;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

#sc-T1-c {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 84%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: width 0.25s;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

.sc-T1-I {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.sc-T1-I img {
  z-index: 1;
}

#sc-T1-a,
#sc-T1-b {
  display: hidden;
}

#sc-T1-c {
  display: shown;
}

.sc-T1-I .sc-desc {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  opacity: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='maincontent'>
  <div class='layout-T1'>
    <div class='sc-T1'>
      <div class='sc-T1-I' id='sc-T1-a'>
        <img src='/bucket/8LiuyJubP9p8tzqrdFAUdld8XV5jzdTRH-aFJdiHbfM.webp'>
        <div class='sc-desc' id='sc-a-desc'>afdd</div>
      </div>
      <div class='sc-T1-I' id='sc-T1-b'>
        <img src='/bucket/crop.jfif'>
        <div class='sc-desc' id='sc-b-desc'>jnfakd</div>
      </div>
      <div class='sc-T1-I' id='sc-T1-c'>
        <img src='/bucket/8LiuyJubP9p8tzqrdFAUdld8XV5jzdTRH-aFJdiHbfM.webp'>
        <div class='sc-desc' id='sc-c-desc'>uids</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='sc-T2'></div>
</div>
```

also, there is this weird margin in between the showcase elements that I can't seem to get rid of. If someone can figure out how to remove that, It would be much appreciated

Comment: The description is showing next to the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this (replace the image div with an actual `img`). The important part is to use `position: absolute` on the overlay div, and set its parent div as `position: relative`. This will make the overlay div position absolute relative to the parent div. If you do not set `position: relative` on the parent, it will be absolute with respect to the `body` element.

```css
carousel {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: transparent;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.overlay:hover {
color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.square-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<carousel>
  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="overlay">i am overlay 1</div>
    <div class="square-image">i am image 1</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="overlay">i am overlay 2</div>
    <div class="square-image">i am image 2</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="overlay">i am overlay 3</div>
    <div class="square-image">i am image 3</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="overlay">i am overlay 4</div>
    <div class="square-image">i am image 4</div>
  </div>
</carousel>
```